# Keyboard Shortcut To Switch Between Opened Windows

Tags: macos

How do I switch between open windows?

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switches between opened applications, but for example, when I open preferences-window of BetterTouchTool I don't get it shown via <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> will allow you to switch between the open windows of the current application. Very useful.

Comment: Yep, I'm familiar with this keyboard shortcut, however it won't help in this situation.

Comment: @Anonymous What about CMD+<?

Comment: @Anonymous I was trying to write the tilda key, the one that is right above the tab key.

Comment: Yep, and it does not work on a fresh install of Mountain Lion. I'm also used to the Cmd+` shortcut (Cmd+# on my Azerty keyboard).

Comment: What a useful key combination!Thank you for posting this!

Answer (score 4):

By default (on a clean install of Mountain Lion), there is a keyboard shortcut "Move focus to active or next window", <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>, which worked for activating the BetterSnapTool preference window (which is the same deal, activating a window in an app that doesn't have a dock icon).[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch between windos within ONE application, you rather want to use the "Move focus to next window" command, 3 lines below the marked line in the screenshot above.

Answer (score -3):

Shortcut key to switch between opened windows is Alt+Tab

Regards
Shefali

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing OS X and Windows here?