# change the command+tab and command+` behavior in Mountain Lion

Tags: keyboard

When it is a switch between applications, we use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, and when it is a switch within an application, we use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>.

Can I just use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> for all cases, as in Windows?

Comment: Related questions: [1](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2718) [2](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29130) [3](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10502) [4](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58541) [5](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20169) [6](http://superuser.com/questions/45310) [7](http://superuser.com/questions/364315) [8](http://superuser.com/questions/62390)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in OS X, but you can buy and install [witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) for that function.